# RTCweb server side implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, communication, real-time

RTCweb standardization initiative is running very fast (IETF, W3C...)!!

The current specifications focus on browser to browser communications and early partial browser side implementations are popping (Ericsson, Google, Mozilla...).

But what about server side RTCweb solution? rendez-vous server and/or framework, gateway able to bridge SIP, conference server, video/voice mail,..

Is somebody aware of an open source initiative around a server side RTCweb solution/framework?

As RTCweb is based on javascript API, does a nodeJS or other javascript server side engine rtcweb add-on make sense?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is somebody aware of an open source initiative around a server side
>   RTCweb solution/framework?

Up to this day I'm not aware of such solution/framework, mainly because it's probably too early to built server side technology for this upcoming standard, since the specification is still taking shape and there are currently no browser versions which supports this stuff by default or natively without the need of doing extra steps in order to use it.

> As RTCweb is based on javascript API, does a nodeJS or other
>   javascript server side engine rtcweb add-on make sense?

I believe rtcweb (or [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/)) server side "add-on" in any language or platform would make sense, since if it becomes popular there would be a high demand for this stuff from various systems, platforms and languages. I think node.js may be in advantage since this scenario would be a good use case for it's capabilities.